# Does lux's light binding reveal it's target when hit?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does the light binding ability of Lux reveal it's target when hit? For example when firing into a brush?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not. However, you can hear the sound of it hitting an Opponent.
You can then use your E to reveal the target since it gives vision in the brush.

Comment: And her E (Lucent Singularity)